# Desplazamiento de texto de un div sin scroll

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Tengo un div con una serie de enlaces y quiero conseguir este efecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualmente se muestra entero

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y cuando voy reduciendo pantalla se van colocando unos abajo de otros. No sé si hay alguna forma solo con css de realizar esa funcionalidad sin aparecer la barra de scroll.

Dejo mi código por si me podéis dar alguna orientación.

```
        <div class="events-category col-md-12">
            <a href="" id="events-cat-all">All</a>
            <a id="events-cat-1">prueba </a>
            <a id="events-cat-2">prueba</a>
            <a id="events-cat-3">prueba</a>
            <a id="events-cat-4">prueba</a>
            <a id="events-cat-5">prueba</a>
            <a id="events-cat-6">prueba</a>
            <a id="events-cat-7">prueba</a>
            <a id="events-cat-8">prueba</a>
        </div>

.events-category {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 2;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El scroll aparece porque el contenedor que almacena todos los enlaces supera los píxeles del viewport de tu navegador.

Como estás tratando de solucionar un tema relacionado con el diseño responsive, es probable que lo que necesites sea hacer consultas @media.

Las consultas @media se utilizan para definir estilos dependiendo del tamaño del viewport del usuario que visita tu sitio web.

```css
@media (max-width: 1000px) {}
```

Todos los estilos que apliques dentro de las llaves, se mostrarán en pantallas menores de 1000px.

**Te pongo un ejemplo con tu código:**

```css
body {
 background: #1afe49;
 margin: 0
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
 nav {
  display: none
 }
}

nav {
 background: #3d43b4;
 padding: 1em
}

ul {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0
}

li {}

a {
 text-decoration: none
}

nav a {
 color: #fff;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 padding: 0 1em
}

nav a:hover {
 text-decoration: underline
}
```

```html
<body>
 <nav>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="">All</a></li>
   <li><a href="">A</a></li>
   <li><a href="">B</a></li>
   <li><a href="">C</a></li>
   <li><a href="">D</a></li>
   <li><a href="">E</a></li>
   <li><a href="">F</a></li>
   <li><a href="">G</a></li>
   <li><a href="">H</a></li>
   <li><a href="">I</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</body>
```

Lo que básicamente hace el código es que si el dispositivo tiene un tamaño de pantalla menor de 1000px que, por convención, se suele utilizar para tablets y móviles en landscape, hace desaparecer el menú de navegación.

Ahora puedes agregar el mismo menú de navegación pero con otro estilo, compatible con las medidas que, antes, rompían tu página.

Comment: Gracias pero no se si me he explicado bien, lo siento. Lo que me refería en la pregunta si hay alguna manera de mostrar la lista de palabras así, y que sea deslizable hacia el lado, como una especie de slider de palabras.

Answer (score 0):

Solo con CSS es complicado, generalmente se recomienda usar JavaScript para crear un Hamburger menu o Menu hamburguesa, sin embargo, si lo que quieres es hacerlo sin javascript puedes aplicar un font-size con vw en vez de px.

```css
.events-category {
  font-size: 2.5vw!important;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="events-category col-md-12">
  <a href="" id="events-cat-all">All</a>
  <a id="events-cat-1">prueba </a>
  <a id="events-cat-2">prueba</a>
  <a id="events-cat-3">prueba</a>
  <a id="events-cat-4">prueba</a>
  <a id="events-cat-5">prueba</a>
  <a id="events-cat-6">prueba</a>
  <a id="events-cat-7">prueba</a>
  <a id="events-cat-8">prueba</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias pero no se si me he explicado bien, lo siento. Lo que me refería en la pregunta si hay alguna manera de mostrar la lista de palabras así, y que sea deslizable hacia el lado, como una especie de slider de palabras.

Answer (score -1):

Prueba agregando esto

```
.events-category {
    display: flex;
    dverflow-x: auto;
}
```